# Configure QT5.4 with MSVC2013?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013

I installed [Qt 5.4 (32bit, VS 2013, OpenGL)](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.4/5.4.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_opengl-5.4.0.exe) and VisualStudio-2013, configured `PATH` variable like this:

```
PATH = ...;C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2013_opengl\bin
```

When I try compile an project the console shows this issues:

> MAKEFILE_GENERATOR variable not set as a result of parsing : example.pro. Possibly qmake was not able to find files included using "include(..)" - enable qmake debugging to investigate more.

I think it is necessary configure in "system vars" this paths: `C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2013_opengl\include` and `C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2013_opengl\include`, but I know not how to do it.

How do I set up QT5.4 with VisualStudio2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't complicate your life too much, just use the official [Visual Add-in](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.4-opensource.exe) and everything should be up and running in a sec.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A question, VisualStudio-Add-in don't requires visual-studio installed?

Comment: You're welcome! But yes, the add-in do require Visual Studio installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, qt-vsadd-in freeze and I could not install on Windows7, but must have been some error in the operating system, then I try to reinstall.

Comment: When trying to reinstall it says I already installed and I have to remove, but he does not appear on the control panel. I have not had time to try to figure out what happened. :(

Comment: Within Visual Studio, do you have a Qt menu in between View and Project?

Comment: Under "Programs and Features" you should have a entry: "Qt5 Visual Studio Add-in 1.2.4". If it's not there try maybe a third party uninstaller like CCleaner.

Comment: In "Program and Features" and "Revo Uninstaller" there is nothing related. Ccleaner not work for this. I'll try to uninstall and install VisualStudio2013-Community (using "Revo Uninstaller").

Comment: Not quite the question of which version of the "VS", but the problem was the "qt-addin" that crashed during installation. I check all folders (`./users/All Users/` and `./ProgramData`) but cann't find anything related. tried "ccleaner" really is a problem with the "qtaddin", then I'll try to install on another computer. Thanks a lot :)